# How to get changed/sent properties at controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

**Using**

> ASP.NET MVC 4
>
> Entity Framework 5 (Code-first approach)

I have regular controllers and views. The difference here is that I need to get the name of the properties that were actually sent to the controller. This is what I have:

```
public ActionResult Update(ClassX data)
{
    //do something with data
}
```

The problem is that when I use `IDbSet.Attach(entity)` it doesn't know what properties have been changed, it just loads the properties sent from the view, it doesn't load the DB data and "updates" what just came from the view.

Since that was happening I thought about checking for the properties the view sent to the controller, with no luck. If I were able to do that I could change my update method to load the DB data and then update with the new data.

Does anyone have any suggestion for any of the problems?

1. Check for the sent properties
2. Any way to solve the other properties not loading when using `IDbSet.Attach(entity)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    // Load the entity to be updated from the database
    ClassX data = db.ClassXs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    // Modify only the properties that were present in the request 
    // (BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL WITH THAT -> YOUR CODE IS VULNERABLE TO MASS ASSIGNMENT
    // AND THE PROPER SOLUTION IS TO USE A VIEW MODEL WHICH WILL ONLY CONTAIN THE PROPERTIES
    // THAT ARE ALLOWED TO BE UPDATED FROM THE VIEW)
    this.UpdateModel(data);

    // at this stage the data instance will have its properties coming from the view
    // updated with fresh values => now you can commit it to the database
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, but in your example you only receive the `id`. How can I see the properties present in the request? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why do you wanna *see* them? Why care? The `this.UpdateModel(data)` method that I am calling will take care of setting them.

Comment: One other question, I have a Service layer that I use to handle all my business logic, including the update. Since `UpdateModel` is Controller based, how can I work with that inside my Service? I just get the data received at the Controller and pass it to the Service.

Comment: You should not work with that inside the service. Binding request values to a **view model** is the responsibility of the controller, not the service layer. I explicitly stress on the word **view model** which is what you should be using in your controller and populate it from the request values. Then you could map this view model to the corresponding domain model that needs to be updated and passed to the service layer. I would recommend you using AutoMapper for that purpose of mapping betwen your view models and domain models.

Comment: Ok, I'll see how can I get that to work, I'll mark as answer as soon as I get that working. Thanks.